# How to remove dependency to log4net in Release build?

Tags: c#, .net

In my C# project, I use log4net for debugging. But for the Release build, I need to remove any dependency to log4net. I'm not sure what is the right way to go about it.

Having #if DEBUG ... endif through the code is very messy, and I have to manually add/remove the Reference to log4net when I compile in Debug or Release mode.

The other option I thought about it is to somehow switch the "real" lotg4net with a mock class in the Release build, but I'm not sure how to do this.

What is the best way to remove a dependency, log4net in my case, in the Release build?

Comment: Mocks are for testing. The production version of which tend to fall along the lines of Inversion of Control or Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Along the lines of M.Babcock's answer: you are after dependency inversion.  You do not necessarily *have* to use a dependency injection container but you will need to abstract your logging.

Something like this:

```
public interface ILog
{
    void Trace(string message);
    void Debug(string message);
    void Error(string message);
    // and whatever you need
}
```

Then you have different implementations:

```
public class NullLog : ILog { ... } // does nothing --- all calls are empty
public class Log4NetLog : ILog { ... } // initializes Log4Net and does logging
```

You could then use a static class as the main entry point:

```
public static class Log
{
    private ILog log = new NullLogger();

    public static void Assign(ILog log)
    {
        this.log = log;
    }

    public static void Debug(string message)
    {
        log.Debug(message);
    }

    // ...and other implementations...
}
```

Now you need to wire this up in your startup code.  Here you can use a container or use conditional compilation:

```
#if DEBUG
    Log.Assign(new Log4NetLogger);
#endif
```

These are the broad strokes.  I have some logging infrastructure code as part of my service bus: http://shuttle.codeplex.com/

ILog: 
http://shuttle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c49f328edd17#Shuttle.Core%2fsource%2fShuttle.Core.Infrastructure%2fLogging%2fILog.cs

NullLog:
http://shuttle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c49f328edd17#Shuttle.Core%2fsource%2fShuttle.Core.Infrastructure%2fLogging%2fNullLog.cs

Log4NetLog:
http://shuttle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c49f328edd17#Shuttle.Core%2fsource%2fShuttle.Core.Infrastructure.Log4Net%2fLog4NetLog.cs

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Dependency Injection is the best option here. Abstract your logging library away from your physical implementation by adding a DI container in between (Logging is one of the poster children for DI/IoC and AOP). Offload your logging preference to a configuration setting that can be ignored for Release builds. You'll save yourself a lot of headaches.